# How to read a string from C# socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

I a very new to C#, so please be aware of that. Currently I am writing a program where a server sends messages to me, that are in format of JSON-strings. How can I read a string from the inputstream of that socket?

Comment: There is lots of information available on reading data from a socket. Your question fails to provide any evidence that you've done any research, or tried anything. Please explain what you've tried, and what _specifically_ you need help with. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, and overly broad questions like this one are inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize JSON-Strings into the proper object with the [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: While this is *true*, it doesn't really address the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a socket as a `Stream` (for use with most common serializers) by using `NetworkStream`; however, there is a very important thing to consider: "framing". Since you say "messages" (rather than "message"), it sounds like multiple payloads will be sent on the same socket. TCP just represents an ordered byte-stream; if you're sending one message, this is easy - just pass the `NetworkStream` to your chosen deserializer, and: job done. But not so easy if you want to transfer multiple payloads over a single connection, since the two ends need to agree on how to know where each payload starts and ends, which is "framing". For text protocols, a common framing mechanism might be to terminate each payload with a sentinel such as a line-end (some combination of CR/LF), or a nul character (byte zero). For binary protocols, this commonly means using a length prefix (in an agreed format) *before* each message. Unfortunately, in both cases you usually need to buffer the stream until you have a complete payload (noting that you might end up with "a payload and a bit of the next payload" or similar), and use a `MemoryStream` (or similar) on each buffered frame in turn.

Note that you can also use `StreamReader` to access a `Stream` in terms of `string` via an `Encoding`; this may be useful if your deserializer takes `TextReader` or `string`.

More recently, the "pipelines" API can replace the `Stream` metaphor, but a: not all serializers support "pipelines" yet, and b: it is quite an advanced topic, so probably not great for "very new to C#" reasons; but if you're interested, I have a multi-part blog series [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html).

Comment: Yep, I am totally on your side. Sadly the network standard that I got is really crappy, there is no token for Message end defined...

Comment: @F_Schmidt then... how do you expect to partition the data? Are you just going to count braces and look for a `}` or `]` (since you mention JSON) that takes you back to zero?

Comment: I guess so......